# Struts2 <s:token> with multiple AJAX Call using jquery

Tags: java, jquery, struts2

I need to make few pages CSRF protected in my project. I am using struts2.

I have a page where I make multiple JQuery AJAX calls at the same time to get data from server.

My problem is that if I pick token parameter from JSP and send it with one of the JQuery AJAX 
calls then what about other AJAX Calls because once the token is sent to server that token will be invalidated after use.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Other Ajax calls need to generate a token. And because you need to keep the token on the server you could make a separate request for the token before posting the data. Then compare the token sent along with the server token, and if they are equal then execute an action.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,If I have understood the answer correctly,you mean to say that I need to execute an AJAX call to get a token before I execute actual AJAX call to get the data. Wouldn't it be some kind of security risk?

Comment: There's no any risk in generating token and sending with the response, as you have seen Struts implemented a token interceptor to handle tokens coming from the user interface.

Comment: I have not tried it yet. I need to see how I can i implements it. I am not sure , If there can be multiple struts token in a single JSP. May be I can have my own token checking and generation code.